# Why does my button point to an aspx.cs file from the wrong page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a web project in Visual Studio Express 2013.  Currently it has a home page and 2 form pages. The first form page, aff.aspx, works perfectly and emails the form data to me when the submit button has been clicked. My second page, adv.aspx, looks how I want it to look, but the submit button at the bottom of the form calls the aspx.cs file from aff.aspx instead of its own. How can I tell the button to call adv.aspx.cs instead of aff.aspx.cs?

Thank you in advance for any help that you can offer.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue a few times.

It normally happens when an .aspx page has been renamed, but the `class` name hasn't been changed in *all* places in the new copy of the file.

So, open your `.aspx` page, your `.aspx.cs` and `.aspx.cs.design` files, and check that the names all refer to the new project & class name.

For example, in the following `SomeWebpage.aspx` page, the project (SomeProject) & class (SomeWebpage) name are mentioned twice, in the first line:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableViewState="false" 
EnableTheming="false" StylesheetTheme=""  
AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="SomeWebpage.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="SomeProject.SomeWebpage" %>
```

.. and if that line ended with this...

```
Inherits="SomeProject.SomeOriginalWebpageName" %>
```

... then this would cause your issue.

Comment: This was the issue, but updating the inherits did not fix the issue. I had to copy the code and paste it into another file to make it work. There was likely a better way, but that was the quickest. Thank you for your response.